# Создание сложного меню с анимацией slide с помощью Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть сложное меню с двумя подкатегориями.
 Однако анимация срабатывает некорректно при клике на вторую подкатегорию (заново начинается анимация второй подкатегории, и только потом переходит на третью подкатегорию).
По-моему, этот баг из-за этой строчки кода, однако без нее при повторном нажатии не срабатывает анимация. Есть ли другой выход из этой ситуации, или же другой метод РЕШЕНИЯ этой задачи?

```js
$('.category li').children('.r_div').animate({
    width: '0%'    
  },0);
```

```js
$('.category li').click(function(event) {
  $('.category li').children('.r_div').css('display', 'none');
  $(this).children('.r_div').css('display', 'block');
  $('.category li').children('.r_div').animate({
    width: '0%'    
  },0);
  $(this).children('.r_div').animate({
    width: '100%'    
  },300);
});
$('.cat_2 li').click(function(event) {
  $('.cat_2 li').children('.cat_3').css('display', 'none');
  $(this).children('.cat_3').css('display', 'block');
  
  $(this).children('.cat_3').animate({
    width: '100%'    
  },300);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  padding:0;
}

.category li {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #eee;
  cursor:pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.category ul{
  width:100%;
}

.r_div , .cat_3{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width:0%;
  background: #eee;
  left:100%;
  border-left:3px solid #000;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category">
  <li>
    Menu #1
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul class="cat_2">
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #2
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #3
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #4
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #5
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul class="cat_2">
        <li>Test5
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: у вас тту как минимум проблема в том, что вложенное меню содержится в текущем li целиком, поэтому кликая в дочернее, вызывается клик и на верхний уровень.

Answer (score 1):

клик по `cat_2 > li` после исполнения вызывает всплытие события ([bubbling](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling)), в результате `click` по `.category > li` снова выполняетcя. Заглушить всплытие можно функцией [event.stopPropagation();](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F)

```js
$('.category > li').click(function(event) {

    //console.log("$('.category > li').click()");

    $('.category > li > .r_div').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).children('.r_div').css('display', 'block');
    
    $('.category > li > .r_div').animate({
        width: '0%'    
    },0);
    
    $(this).children('.r_div').animate({
        width: '100%'    
    },300);
});

$('.cat_2 > li').click(function(event) {

    //console.log("$('.cat_2 > li').click()");

    $('.cat_2 > li > .cat_3').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).children('.cat_3').css('display', 'block');
    
    $(this).children('.cat_3').animate({
        width: '100%'    
    },300);
    
    event.stopPropagation(); // стопэ
    
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  padding:0;
}

.category li {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #eee;
  cursor:pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.category ul{
  width:100%;
}

.r_div , .cat_3{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width:0%;
  background: #eee;
  left:100%;
  border-left:3px solid #000;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category">
  <li>
    Menu #1
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul class="cat_2">
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #2
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #3
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #4
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #5
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul class="cat_2">
        <li>Test5
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: почти сработало, однако теперь при нажатии открытое меню закрывается

Comment: Подробнее опишите, так-то вроде всё норм.

Comment: у меня при нажатии на элемент меню вторая подкатегория теперь закрывается

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли добиться этого эффекта с помощью transition? Вроде бы сработало только не смог реализовать для этих менюшек

Comment: transition не для этого, если вы про выпадающие меню. А вот hover самое оно.